# How to build a structure with one field per function call or macro?

Tags: c, struct

I want to send a structure via a socket. I don't want to use IDL to specify the structure, but do it more dynamically. I want to add several function calls or macro calls in the code, e.g. `SendInt32(someInteger)`. The structure should contain one field per function call in the code. Multiple calls at the same code line (e.g. loop) should update the same field. How to build this structure dynamically?

It's also required to calculate the sum of the length of the fields. Let's ignore how the remote endpoint reads the structure for the moment.

```
SendInt32(1);    // (1)
SendInt16(2);    // (2)
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  SendInt32(i);  // (3)
}
```

the implementation of the `Send` functions should produce a structure, as the following:

```
struct {
  uint16_t size = 10;  // sizeof(first) + sizeof(second) + sizeof(third)
  int32_t first = 1;   // (1)
  int16_t second = 2;  // (2)
  int32_t third = 9;   // (3)
}
```

Is this possible in C?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Show more detail of the required behavior.

Comment: Don't expect too much magic from C language. Macros can add some magic, at the cost of harder to read an maintain code. But C structs have to be defined at compile time. And C readers expect that `SendInt32(0); SendInt32(1);` and `for(int i=0; i<2; i++) SendInt(i);` will have same behaviour. My advice is that you should rethink your design...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate your data in a buffer of bytes, e.g.:

```
size_t packet_size = 0;

unsigned char buf[1024];

void AccumulateInt32(int32_t n)
{
  memcpy(buf + packet_size, &n, sizeof n);
  packet_size += sizeof n;
}
```

And then you can take `packet_size` and `buf[]` and actually send.

Endianness, error checking and better API are left as an exercise.

Comment: What do you mean with better API? Rethink the whole design?

Comment: @martin I mean, don't use hard-coded buffers or buffer sizes.

Comment: Each function call should have a position to be updated in the buffer. For example `SendInt32(i)` in the loop in the question updates `third`. I could achieve this by adding an index integer to each function call: `SetInt32(int index, int32_t n)`. Is there any chance to get rid of the index? Something like `__LINE__`